# Python csv transpose

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file which looks something like this:

```
Name,A 
Age,23
DOB,26th,Jan
Anniversary,15th,May
Name,B 
Age,23
DOB,26th,Jan
Anniversary,15th,May
Name,C 
Age,23
DOB,26th,Jan
Anniversary,15th,May
Name,D 
Age,23
DOB,26th,Jan
Anniversary,15th,May
```

I would like convert the first column into a common header for the rest of the data. I want it look like this:

```
Name,Age,DOB,Anniversary
A,23,26th Jan,15th May
B,23,26th Jan,15th May
C,23,26th Jan,15th May
D,23,26th Jan,15th May
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer.

```
with open(file,'r') as f:
    final = []
    counter = 0
    details = []
    for line in f:
        details.append(line.split(',')[1])
        counter += 1
        if counter == 4:
            counter = 0
            final.append(details)
             details = []
```

Now you can out to the file iterating over your `final` dict

Comment: I tried transposing the whole thing but fails because the entire thing get's transposed into a matrix of 2 X (number of columns)